# Does Scalatags generate HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scala, scalatags

I saw some Scala code that appears to generate HTML...

```
  def pagePlay: TypedTag[dom.raw.HTMLElement] = div{
    val levels = Array(
      (10, "Easy game; you are allowed 10 misses."),
      (5, "Medium game; you are allowed 5 misses."),
      (3, "Hard game; you are allowed 3 misses.")
    )
    div(
      p("Inspired from ")(a(href:="http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/hangman/", target:="_blank","Yii's demo")),
      p("This is the game of Hangman. You must guess a word, a letter at a time.\n" +
        "If you make too many mistakes, you lose the game!"),
      form(id := "playForm")(
        for((level,text) <- levels) yield {
          val levelId = s"level_${level}"
          div(`class`:="radio")(
            input(id:=levelId, `type`:="radio", name:="level", onclick:={ ()=>
              Model.level() = level
            }, {if(level == Model.level()) checked:="checked"}),
            label(`for`:=levelId, style:="padding-left: 5px")(text)
          )
        }, br,
        input(`type`:="button", value:="Play!", `class`:="btn btn-primary", onclick:={ () =>
          if(Model.level() > 0) {
            Model.start()
            goto(pageGuess)
          }else{
            dom.alert("Please select level!")
          }
        })
      )
    )
  }
```

^ Is this ScalaTag code actually generating HTML that can be read by a simple web crawler with no javascript support, or is it generating Javascript that is modifying the DOM to produce divs and paragraphs and what not?

I tried reading the documentation, but for div and p there was none other than "Pattern: div: Tags.this.ConcreteHtmlTag[html.Div]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses both, well at least now it does:

From the docs:

```
Although Scalatags was originally a HTML-String generation library, it now
ships with an additional backend that runs only on ScalaJS.
```

Furthermore:

> The DOM backend provides an additional method .render on all Scalatags fragments, which converts the fragment into a DOM tree:

```
val elem = div.render
assert(elem.children.length == 0)
elem.appendChild(p(1, "wtf", "bbq").render)
assert(elem.children.length == 1)
val pElem = elem.children(0).asInstanceOf[Paragraph]
assert(pElem.childNodes.length == 3)
assert(pElem.textContent == "1wtfbbq")
As you can see, you can manipulate DOM elements directly, calling standard DOM APIs like .children, .appendChild, etc.
```

> As you can see, you can manipulate DOM elements directly, calling standard DOM APIs like .children, .appendChild, etc. Which as you know are Javascript!

Comment: And the you can convert that into a string which is rendered in Play's template engine.

Comment: If you want to generate HTML, you should `import scalatag.Text.all._`. If you want it to generate only Javascript DOM elements, you can use `import scalatags.JsDom.all._` as you would have done for your example above. 

While you can in theory call `.innerHTML` on the DOM elements generated by `JsDom`, you shouldn't: doing so wipes out event listeners and possibly other attributes. Furthermore, `JsDom` doesn't work on a Scala-JVM server. 

So you should use scalatags.Text. If you want code shared between both, there's docs on how to do so http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/#Cross-backendCode